# Swift formatting currency returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to format a number as a currency.

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB")
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle

let limit = formatter.numberFromString("12.99") as? NSDecimalNumber
```

However, the constant limit is returned a nil. The weird thing is that this piece of code was working up until recently but not sure what may have changed. Does the example look okay or am I missing something?

EDIT

To give context, I am trying to parse a string number (from an input element) to a decimal number for storing as currency value. My error appears setting the number style, I was using `.CurrencyStyle` but should use `.DecimalStyle`.

Answer (score 3):

As a first test I tried

```
println(formatter.stringFromNumber(12.99))  // prints "£12.99"
```

Then I tried

```
let limit = formatter.numberFromString("£12.99") as? NSDecimalNumber  // gives nil
```

But

```
let limit = formatter.numberFromString("£12.99") // gives 12.99
```

Whereas

```
let limit = formatter.numberFromString("12.99") // gives nil
```

So the currency symbol is mandatory

Comment: Thanks for answering. I used the wrong numberStyle for the formatter.